# Passing Environment variable to Mainframe JVM

Tags: properties, jvm, mainframe, zos, jcl

I am running a JAVA Mainframe JAR.  It is working successfully using the IBM JVMLDM fro z/OS.  My next step was to integrate an in-house logging framework. I am required to pass several environment variables(user system properties) into the JVM using a STDENV DD statement in the JCL.  I am using the environment variables provided by IBM (documentation) within a PARM file as follows:

```
IJO="$IJO -DCAR_PROP=6123548595"
EXPORT IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS="$IJO "
```

I am also using the following environment variable in a similar manner:

```
IJO="$IJO -DCAR_PROP=6123548595"
EXPORT JZOS_JVM_OPTIONS="$IJO "
```

Neither of these options are working as the property still fails to be captured by the JAR.  Looking for some insight as to what might be the issue with the statement with which I may not be familiar.

DOCUMENTATION
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.iean500/bcdbatch.htm

Comment: Could you please post your complete startup JCL? Have you tried adding the`+T` parameter to enable JZOS-tracing? This should show all environment variables JZOS has picked up and the JVM-options used. You have noted that system properties are case-sensitive? An all-caps property like `CAR_PROP` looks unusual for a java program...

Answer (score 0):

Does using lower-case `export` work?   i.e.

```
IJO="$IJO -DCAR_PROP=6123548595"
export IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS="$IJO "
```

Comment: That was  typo on my part.  I am using a lower-case "export" in the JCL.